# How do I fetch Google reviews in my Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-api

I am a junior RoR developer. I am having trouble integrating the Google business API with my App. My purpose is to fetch Google reviews for my application.

As per the google documentation

https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data#list_all_reviews

It suggest to hit `https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v3/accounts/<your_account_name>/locations/<your_location_name>/reviews`

But this is too vague for me.
Can anyone help me out with the steps to integrate google reviews in a rails app.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what have you tried?  your account would probably be the account of your google business location would also be the location of your business.

Comment: I have gained permission and obtained the client ID and auth key. After this, I included the API key in config.rb.   And then I hit  https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v3/accounts/<your_account_name>/locations/<your_location_name>/reviews.  I feel the steps are incomplete, thanks for the revert.

Comment: How have you gained permission? Have you logged in the user using the client id and client secret?  api key is only going to give you access to public data so thats not going to help you access a users business data.   Do you have an access token? if so did you send it along with your request?   I suspect you havent read though the documentation enough yet.

Comment: Yes, i have filled out the Business specification form and have been granted permission. I do have the client secret and client Id, but I am not sure which Rails directory it should go in. And I put the access token in Application_contrroller.rb. I have read the documentation, however I am having a tough time to understand it.